# trivia bug in bash script

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

aa=$( ps -e   | grep "chrome" | awk '{print $1;}')
for i in $aa
   do
     gnome-terminal --tab -e" sudo cpulimit -p $i -l 35 " 
   done
```

when i run it i get error missing argument e 
 i want it when a chrome process get run to get all process related  parent and children and safe them in aa variable then i open the gnome terminal to cpulimit one by one , any help pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error should give you a hint: Just add a space after `-e`.

Comment: there ıs no hınt just as ı mentıoned sır and ı already put * thank u for replyıng :) `Failed to parse arguments: Missing argument for -e`

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein: You probably misunderstood me. Put a space between `-e` and `"sudo cpulimit ...`.

Comment: yes sir u are right  thank u btw i want to ask about final thing i want to open the gnome all taped in one window for every loop not to open gnome window in each iteration so can u help me in this

Answer (score 0):

`pgrep` is a handy tool to extract PIDs based on a program name:

```
pgrep chrome | 
while read pid; do
  gksudo cpulimit -p $pid -l 35
done
```

Comment: thank u sir for replying but i want to save it in variable aa= $somevalue to do more further things later using this variable

Comment: and i want to make inside the for loop to open gnome terminal and also in each iteration make the open gnome terminal to be tap not in each loop open new independent terminal windows